# How to create N spans with no spaces in between in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

To create `n` `span`s next to each other I do:

```
<% n.times do |i| %> 
  <%= content_tag(:span, i + 1) %> 
<% end %>
```

The problem is that there is a space between the created `span`s.

So, I tried to create them in one line:

```
<% spans = "".html_safe %>
  <% n.times do |i| %> 
    <% spans += content_tag(:span, i + 1) %> 
  <% end %>
<%= spans %>
```

Indeed, now the `span`s are close to each other (no space in between).

However, I feel that this workaround is dirty.

How could achieve the same with a cleaner code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the HTML source you can see it's not a space, but a line-break (which in HTML is displayed as a space). If you put everything in one line the spaces are gone:

```
<% n.times do |i| -%><%= content_tag(:span, i + 1) %><% end -%>
```

This gives me the following output:

```
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
```

Comment: When I try this there are no spaces. Do you have any css that sets paddings or margins on spans?

Comment: Well, your modified code works. BTW, `-` is not needed in `-%>` (`%>` works as well).

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's just my habit to use `-%>`. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<% (0..n).map do |i| 
  content_tag(:span, i + 1) %> 
end -%>
```

Or

```
<% n.times do |i| %> 
<%= content_tag(:span, i + 1) %> 
<% end %>
```